# Error whilst running solidity with python(py-solc)

Tags: solidity, python

I have been running my code which involves deployment of smart contract to Ethereum Ropsten network. I ran this successfully for some time but last week did installed another software after which  started getting these errors:

```
command: solc --combined-json abi,asm,ast,bin,bin-runtime,clone-bin,devdoc,interface,opcodes,userdoc
return code: 1
stderr:
stdout:
Invalid option to --combined-json: clone-bin
```

**EDIT** I'm running this on Jupyter notebook where environmental variable for python3.6 is set up. I have no clue why I'm getting them. Anyone can help?

Comment: This is compiler error - please see my complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53633041/8222863)

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of solc has removed few options.

> The --clone-bin and --combined-json clone-bin command line options were removed.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html

You can downgrade the version if this functionality is required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. its actually Jupyter notebook output